# Way to check which pointers were not freed in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

My code is already written in C, and I'm getting memory leak errors.
I'm using malloc and realloc in many places, is there a way to check which pointers weren't freed? 
Is there any report that could point me into the right direction?

This code involves array of pointers which holds pointer to structs, and linked list of structs. There are some other dynamic allocations in the code as well.

This is the declaration:

```
user **arrMen = NULL;
int menSize = 5;
womanUser *womHead = NULL;
```

This is how I call the function :

```
freeAll(arrMen, womHead, &menSize);
```

And this is the way I'm freeing the arrays:

```
void freeAll(user **arrMen, womanUser *womHead,int *menSize)
{
    womanUser *current = womHead;
    womanUser *previous = current;
    int i;
    //free all pointers in woman list
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (current->womData->name != NULL)
            free(current->womData->name);
        if (current->womData->lastName != NULL)
            free(current->womData->lastName);
        if (current->womData->age != NULL)
            free(current->womData->age);
        if (current->womData->userName != NULL)
            free(current->womData->userName);
        if (current->womData->pass != NULL)
            free(current->womData->pass);
        if (current->womData->desc != NULL)
            free(current->womData->desc);
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
        free(previous);
    }
    //free all pointer in men array
    for (i = 0; i < *menSize; i++)
    {
        if (arrMen[i]->name != NULL)
            free(arrMen[i]->name);
        if (arrMen[i]->lastName != NULL)
            free(arrMen[i]->lastName);
        if (arrMen[i]->age != NULL)
            free(arrMen[i]->age);
        if (arrMen[i]->userName != NULL)
            free(arrMen[i]->userName);
        if (arrMen[i]->pass != NULL)
            free(arrMen[i]->pass);
        if (arrMen[i]->desc!= NULL)
            free(arrMen[i]->desc);
    }
    if (arrMen != NULL)
        free(arrMen);
}
```

The program is running and functioning as expected, but it is suffering from memory leak, and I just can't find what I'm doing wrong, or where are the pointer I didn't not free.

Comment: 1. Use [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/). 2. `free(NULL)` is safe, so all of your `if (x != NULL) free(x);` lines could (and should) be replaced with simply `free(x)`. 3. We can't really tell what you're leaking since you don't show the declarations for your structures nor the code where you allocate memory for them.  But again, use valgrind.

Comment: ... but if I had to guess: do you need to free `arrMen[i]` on each iteration of the loop?  The way that you seem to make individual allocations for everything hints that you do.  (It'd usually be better style and would be simpler to reduce allocations, such as by having an array of `user` structs directly instead of having an array of pointers to `user` structs.)

Comment: The initialization in `womanUser *previous = current;` serves no  purpose.

Comment: Assuming that age is an integer, making the member `age` a pointer to dynamically allocated storage seems to serve little purpose other that to waste memory.  A dynamically allocated integer requires a pointer, the allocated integer, the heap management header for the allocated block, and the allocated block will typically have 8 byte or 16 byte alignment, where you could probably simply make the member an integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tool such as Valgrind (on Linux) is your best bet for leak detection and debugging, second to straightforward careful programming - every time you make an allocation, code the matching deallocation at the same time.  The debugger in recent versions of VC++ will also report memory leaks on termination I think.

In this specific case however it seems likely that @jamesdlin has spotted it.  You free `arrMen` without first freeing its elements:

```
for (i = 0; i < *menSize; i++)
{
    free(arrMen[i]->name);
    free(arrMen[i]->lastName);
    free(arrMen[i]->age);
    free(arrMen[i]->userName);
    free(arrMen[i]->pass);
    free(arrMen[i]->desc);

    free( arrMen[i] ) ;  // <<< Free the structure
                         //     after its members
}

free(arrMen);
```

Note that freeing a null pointer is defined and safe, so checking for NULL every time serves no purpose.  What you might do is set each pointer *to* NULL, so that if any code later attempts to dereference it, it will at least cause a run-time error.  For example you might have:

```
for (i = 0; i < *menSize; i++)
{
    free(arrMen[i]->name);
    free(arrMen[i]->lastName);
    free(arrMen[i]->age);
    free(arrMen[i]->userName);
    free(arrMen[i]->pass);
    free(arrMen[i]->desc);

    memset( arrMen[i], sizeof(*arrMen[i]), 0 ) ;
    free( arrMen[i] ) ;  // <<< Free the structure
                         //     after its members
    arrMen[i] = NULL ;
}

free(arrMen);
arrMen = NULL ;
```

Comment: Note that the good zeroing idea is not applied to the members' referenced data though. IOWS, `free(arrMen[i]->name);` --> `size_t sz = arrMen[i]->name ? strlen(arrMen[i]->name) + 1, 0; memset(arrMen[i]->name, sz, 0); free(arrMen[i]->name);`

Comment: @chux The intent was simply to set the _pointer_ members to zero as a less cluttered (or perhaps lazy) method than explicitly assigning each to NULL. The non-pointer methods, I am less concerned with. It might be a security/privacy concern in some applications. I was expecting the UB police to pick up on the assumption that all zero bytes has the same effect as assigning NULL.

Comment: I agree about the less concern with the non-pointer types.  Still I have found scrubbing all data before freeing advantageous too and not so time expensive.  IAC, I'd expect a `freeWoman()`, `freeMan()` routines  should exist.- allowing simplifications to `freeAll()`.